# getGsmSignalStrength() always returns '99'

Tags: android, signal-strength

Do to the Licensing check delivering a "Not Licensed" response with no or low connection, I have been trying a work around. I wanted to check the signal strength and if it is over 50% (15) or returns a 99 because of no connection, I want it to bypass the check until the next time the app is started with a better signal. This way no authorized user should ever see the NOT LICENSED response.

Question 1: When using getGsmSignalStrength() does only return phone/3g/4g strength or wifi strength as well. If the user is in wifi mode than it should work as well? I do know how to check to see if wifi is connected, so I can always use that to check wifi if needed.

Question 2: getGsmSignalStrength() is always returning a value of '99' even when I am staring at my phone and it is showing full strength.

The entire purpose of ConnecetivityCheck.java is check then continue. Right now I just have it automatically jumping over the check and showing Toast box with the getGsmSignalStrength() number, but this is always showing '99'.

Please Help, thank you.
Below I have attached my code...

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.emsprotocols.ilpaemsprotocols"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<!-- PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<!-- LICENSE PERMISSIONS -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<!-- USES -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".ProtocolsSplashActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
```

The .Java file

```
package com.emsprotocols.ilpaemsprotocols;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectivityCheck extends Activity {
TelephonyManager        Tel;
MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);         

    /* Update the listener, and start it */
    MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProtocolsMMenuActivity.class));  
        ConnectivityCheck.this.finish();
}

/* Called when the application is minimized */
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();
  Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
 }

 /* Called when the application resumes */
@Override
 protected void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
  Tel.listen(MyListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}

/* —————————– */
 /* Start the PhoneState listener */
/* —————————– */
 private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
 {
   /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
   @Override
   public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
   {
      int strengthAmplitude = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();

      super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GSM Cinr = "
         + String.valueOf(strengthAmplitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

 };/* End of private Class */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: It should only be GSM signal strength.

Question 2: I can't find anything wrong with your code, are you sure that you have a GSM signal? If you live in the US is more likely that you are using a CDMA network. There are other ways to get that signal strength: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html)

Comment: I am in the US. DOH! well that would explain why it is only coming up 99. LOL. Thank You. It is always the little things you over look. Do you know the range of CDMA?

Comment: No sorry, but that info should not be too hard to find. Good luck!

Comment: What is the range of CDMA? its always negative dBm so not sure how that works for percentages.